# Explicitly change Twitter's shared URL on iOS's Safari

Tags: ios5, twitter, safari, share, canonical-link

iOS' Safari has now a built in `Share on Twitter` functionality.

[image: iOS Safari's Menu]

---

Where can i specify the URL to be shared ? **Can i explicitly type-in another URL ?**

The problem is that i have a mobile version of my website, hosted on a different domain.
And i would like to be able to share http://example.com while being on http://m.example.com.

Are there any solutions ? Can this be done using `<meta rel="canonical" />` ?